# Locating an entity from a Minecraft crash-report in NBTExplorer

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've had a ticking entity issue on my MC server that causes the server to crash as soon as anyone loads in. As the server crashes when I load in, I can't /kill that entity (crashes instantly) and can't do it from the command line as the chunk the entity is in isn't loaded until someone connects (which then crashes the server).

I'm trying to delete that entity using NBTExplorer and the info I have from the crash report. However, I'm having trouble locating the entity in the world folder.

Here's the crash report info...

```
-- Entity being ticked --
Details:
        Entity Type: minecraft:witch (net.minecraft.class_1640)
        Entity ID: 612
        Entity Name: Avilon Dyck the Witch
        Entity's Exact location: 877.41, 77.94, -2004.70
        Entity's Block location: World: (877,77,-2005), Section: (at 13,13,11 in 54,4,-126; chunk contains blocks 864,-64,-2016 to 879,319,-2001), Region: (1,-4; contains chunks 32,-128 to 63,-97, blocks 512,-64,-2048 to 1023,319,-1537)
        Entity's Momentum: 0.00, -0.08, 0.00
        Entity's Passengers: []
        Entity's Vehicle: null
```

I can tell it's in r1.-4.mca, but can't figure out anything beyond that i.e. which chunk it's in...

Any idea how I can locate this from the info given in the crash report so that I can delete the offending entity from my world folder?

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: you can use a [tool like this](https://minecraft.tools/en/coordinate-calculator.php) to figure out the correct chunk. Look for `in world at (54, -126)`. or I guess it should be `Chunk [20, 2]` in this region file.